# Tensorflow freezing for large amounts of time, randomly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow is randomly freezing when training for large amounts of time, I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this? I have an example below:

```
2016-08-23 23:16:11.392346: step 160, loss = 35.74 (0.0 examples/sec; 536.818 sec/batch)
2016-08-23 23:16:11.803893: step 170, loss = 35.45 (273.4 examples/sec; 0.037 sec/batch)
```

I'm running on GPU.

Comment: Many factors could affect the performance of an application running on your system. I would check the following : Where are you getting the training data from? Is it from the local disk or via the network? Are you running on a shared machine? How many other processes are running, and what is the load on the machine?

Comment: Its my machine, training examples are loaded into memory. My training dataset is about 15GB so I loaded it and then pull from memory. I am currently trying to set up tensorflow's queing system properly, I am wondering if that may have been the issue.

Comment: How much memory does your machine have? 15GB is a significant amount of data. How are you loading them into memory? Is your machine running other processes that also compete for memory?

Comment: 64GB, nothing else is comepeting. It usually starts again after 10 minutes or so.

Comment: Maybe that will seem ridiculous but for me the issue seemed to come from the electrical alimentation of the computer. Unplugging and replugging solved it :)

Comment: I can't tell if you are serious or not...